# Sum distances with units in date range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Given a table with dates in one row and corresponding values in another row (with units), is there a way to automatically sum the values for a specified dynamic date range? For example, given the following table, say I wanted to sum the distances for the last 3 days up to the present day. In this case B2:D2 = 10.

|  | A | B | C | D | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-27 | 2021-08-28 | 2021-08-29 | 2021-08-30 | ... |
| 2 | 3 mi | 4 mi | 0 mi | 6 mi | ... |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |

I have experimented with numerous combinations of SUM, SUMIF, SUMPRODUCT/COUNTIF, ARRAYFORMULA, and SUBSTITUTE/REGEXEXTRACT, but can't find the right combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=arrayformula(sum(value(filter(regexreplace(A2:D2,"\ .*",),A1:D1>today()-3))))
```

[image]

Alternatively:

```
=arrayformula(sum(value(filter(regexreplace(A2:D2,"\ .*",),A1:D1>max(A1:D1)-3))))
```